# Can I easily make a template function that takes an arbitrary container of an arbitrary type and operates on it?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to get something like this to work:

```
// This method is wrong, won't work, need your help
template < template <typename T> class U >
void foo(U& u) 
{
  T& blah = *u.begin();
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  vector<int> myVec(4, 10);
  foo<vector<int> >(myVec); // This is how I want to call it, even better if I can leave the parameters out and just do foo(myVec);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Really what I want to do is avoid the following because it seems redundant:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void foo(U& u)
{
T& blah = *u.begin(); 
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  vector<int> myVec(4, 10);
  foo<int, std::vector<int> >(myVec); // first int in parameters is redundant cause I already provide int as arg to vector
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: what compiler are you using? are you able to use the "auto" keyword?

Comment: gcc. I can access auto if I enable std=c++0x. I guess I could try that, but I want it to run on c++98 as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do :

```
template < typename U>
void foo(U& u) 
{
  typename U::value_type blah = *u.begin();
}
```

Comment: You answered before @OliCharlesworth. You deserve points too.

Answer (score 8):

You can just do:

```
template <typename U>
void foo(U& u)
{
    typedef typename U::value_type T;
    T& blah = *u.begin(); 
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  vector<int> myVec(4, 10);
  foo(myVec);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Let's generalize this problem, what if I was passing in template that was not an stl container and did not have value_type defined. How would I solve the same problem? Possible, without actually defining the value type for my custom template?

Comment: @anio: I have an answer for your question. It may not be what you would ideally want, but it works. Type tagging. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
#include <vector>

template <template <typename, typename> class Cont, typename T, typename Alloc>
void foo(Cont<T,Alloc>& cont)
{
    T& blah = *cont.begin();
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    std::vector<int> myVec(4, 10);
    foo(myVec);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What's wrong with your original version is that `vector` has an additional template parameter (the allocator type). Also, you need to specify the template parameters, as I'm doing above.

All of this being said, I think I prefer Oli and FreakEnum's version, as it's more generic! :)

Comment: This also works, but its more complex than Oli's solution. What is the benefit to doing the extra work here? Can you explain when I would want to use your version?

Comment: One advantage of this version would be that you could use T as return value or additional parameter. In oli's and FreakEnums version T is out of scope for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you need this to work for container-like types that do not follow STL conventions regarding a `value_type` typedef then you need a tagging system. Here is an example of how you would make this work.

```
template <typename U>
struct foo_tags {
   typedef typename U::value_type value_type;
};

template <typename U>
void foo(U& u)
{
    typedef foo_tags<U>::value_type T;
    T& blah = *u.begin(); 
}

class my_very_special_int_container {
 public:
   int *begin();
};

template <>
struct foo_tags<my_very_special_int_container>
{
    typedef int value_type;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
  vector<int> myVec(4, 10);
  foo(myVec);
  my_very_special_int_container c;
  foo(c);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector<int>::reference` type? Is that what you're asking for?